# Exactly which object have I clicked on?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
           <Border Name="firstborder"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">
            </Border>
            <Border Name="secondborder"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="0"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">
            </Border>
                <Border Name="thirdborder"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="1"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">
            </Border>
            <Border Name="fourthborder"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="1"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">
            </Border>
```

I have the above four Border objects. I want to use visual hit testing to determine which one of these I have clicked on.

```
        // Clear the contents of the list used for hit test results.
        hitResultsList.Clear();

        // Set up a callback to receive the hit test result enumeration.
        VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, null,
            new HitTestResultCallback(MyHitTestResult),
            new PointHitTestParameters(point));

        // Perform actions on the hit test results list. 
        if (hitResultsList.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Visuals Hit: " + hitResultsList.Count);
        }
        Visual visual = hitResultsList[1];
        Console.WriteLine("To string " + visual.ToString()); 
        if ( visual.Equals(secondborder) )
            Console.WriteLine("2nd border ");
        if (visual.Equals(firstborder))
            Console.WriteLine("first border ");
        if (visual.Equals(thirdborder))
            Console.WriteLine("third border ");
        if (visual.Equals(fourthborder))
            Console.WriteLine("4th border ");
```

The debugger tells me that the visual hit test has returned a Border element in hitResultsList[1]. Now I just want to identify which one of the four Border objects is it. How can I do that?

Comment: Why cannot you cast hitResultsList[1] to Border? ((Border)hitResultsList[1]).Name will give you name of this border

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're hit-testing a point from a mouse click? You know that with WPF you don't have to do any of this, right?

Comment: No I am new to WPF, please advise a better a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Console.WriteLine((Border)visual.Name);
```

to print the name of the item to the console. The output should be visible in the Visual Studio Output window.